# Solve Error 500 on Node.JS signup backend

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When trying to test http://localhost:3000/api/users/register I'm getting that cannot GET users/register and when testing it on postman, performing a POST request, I'm getting an 500 error.  Can you please tell me how to solve it?

models/User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

routes/user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    // Check if user already exists
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(409).json({ message: 'User already exists' });
    }

    // Create new user
    const user = new User({ username, password });
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error TEST' });
  }
});



router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error TEST2' });
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb+srv://mike:Valentina14.@cluster0.pfkyhf3.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  /*useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,*/
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('MongoDB connected!');
});
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./db');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/users');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);



const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
```

[Screenshot of failed POST request on Postmand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Uw2.png)

I have tried changing the position of the module.exports = router but that didn't work.

Comment: The main problem is that I cannot POST to http://localhost:3000/api/users/register

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the request with params from the Postman to your route whereas your route is set up to accept the body, try to send the request as body from your postman in JSON